# Keep Touch Bar active when app isn't active

Tags: swift, xcode, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am trying to keep the Touch Bar of my app active in the app controls part of the Touch Bar even when using a different app. How can I do this? I know this can be done because I have seen apps e.g. BetterTouchTool to do this.

For more information I am using Swift

Comment: Apple does not provide an API for this. BetterTouchTool is probably using some private API or another kind of trick to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not provide anything for this and apps such as BetterTouchTool use their own code to do this which would be quite complicated.